# Windows network share not acessible

Tags: firewall, network-share, windows-10

This question might appear to be a duplicate but I've not found a solution and have tried a multitude of different "solutions" which have not worked.

**Quick description of the situation:** I'm in need of setting up a Windows Network Share for file exchange of video files for video editing purposes, with a couple of people who do not have direct access to the local network in which the file serving computer resides. The computer is running Windows 10 Pro (probably the root of the cause right there according to lot of discussions I've read over while looking for the solution). In the Network and Sharing settings I've the network set to Private, the workgroup is set to WORKGROUP and Homegroup settings are set to allow Windows to manage homegroup connections.

**What is the problem:** Windows shares are accessible from the local network but not from external networks. The FTP meanwhile works fine.

**What I've done so far:** I've set up the folders and the shares, as well as forwarded the following ports on the router: TCP 139, 445; UDP 137-138; (it's a small, simple network). I already contacted the ISP and confirmed with them that they are not blocking any ports as a security measure. I've also set up a FileZilla which has it set on the router to forward a custom TCP port from external networks over to TCP 21 locally. I tried to access the network shares and the computer from external networks both from a Windows 7 computer and a Windows 10 computer, neither could connect and reported the network location is inaccessible or could not be reached, locally the network shares work fine, meanwhile FTP through the custom port works fine. I even tried to temporary open and forward all ports on the router and disabled the firewall... didn't help, which means I've missed something.

**Last notes:** I'm trying to set up a windows network share because people who are going to be using it are used to this kind of workflow enviroment, FTP server is for the people who are used to FTP enviroment. I tried to

Comment: Small note - after multiple unsuccessful attempts to find a solution and trying different suggestions I've rolled back to a backup restore point which is a fresh install and corresponds to the described state of the situation as described above.

Comment: I would suggest troubleshooting each segment: External IP -> Router first. If you can reach the Router, then do the next segment which is: Router -> PC. Do you see traffic on those ports through Wireshark coming from the Router? If you can access the shares via the local network, config is fine. Just double check that something isn't getting dropped or that traffic is at least hitting the PC. If not, look at the router again and double check your rules?

Comment: The first thing I tried was pinging the computers forth and back (after enabling ping request replies on the router setings) and didn't have problems with receiving responses, which only indicates that something is there. After receiving answer from the ISP I did look with WireShark at what traffic is passing to and from the computer when a computer from an external network is trying to connect, and when the same is done on FTP. I saw the FTP traffic appearing and going through the ports as specified but I did not see any traffic on any of the ports 137-139, 445.

Comment: I also tried accessing the FTP from external networks, and as I mentioned before - it works (which means port forwarding works fine and the computer is partially reachable).

Comment: Another thing I didn't mention before - the computer currently is equipped with only the built-in BitDefender and no additional AV software or firewall.

Comment: Could it perhaps be a new security policy or requirement that I'm simply overlooking? I'm aware that in case of Windows Server you have to specifically enable it for file shares to work, but I've not seen such procedures in the average consumer OS version of Windows just yet.

Comment: `1.` Bitdefender isn't a Microsoft product and as such isn't built-in. `2.` Have you made sure that the inbound File and Printer Sharing rules in the Windows Firewall are correctly configured?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mistook it for Windows Defender .... I don't know why I called it "Bit Defender" ... perhaps due to similarities in the name and the purpose of the software.

Comment: I found where, I think, the problem was...
1)I moved the computer in question closer to the router to which I connected it (previously it was connected to the router through a switch). I left the port forwarding settings unchanged and the ;
2)I once again disabled Firewall and specified the local IP of the computer as DMZ destination;

After I tried to connect to the computer from an external network I was able to access it and see the network shares. I disabled DMZ and successfully reconnected with the computer, I then disabled Windows Firewall and was not able to reconnect afterwards...

Comment: Altho all the rules suppostedly are correctly configured, I will review the firewall again rules and see if I've missed something.